# trying to get sql table data from thinkup

Tags: php, mysql, thinkup

I am using ThinkUp app(social media measurement tool), I have created a table with some datas in ThinkUp database and i am trying to to show the data, using simple query in (class.insightMySQLDAO.php), how do I fix this query?

```
public function getTsExternal(){
    $q = "SELECT * FROM #prefix#tsmentioned ";
    $q = $this->execute($q);
    var_dump($q);
}
```

the result i get is

```
object(PDOStatement)#17 (1) {
  ["queryString"]=>
  string(29) "SELECT * FROM tu_tsmentioned "
}
NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM #prefix#tsmentioned ";
$ps = $this->execute($q);
$row = $this->getDataRowAsArray($ps);
 var_dump($row);
```